# Java Hibernate: Passing current row id to Subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I have two Objects

```
Post {
   long id
   String post
   Date lastUpdate
}

Tracker {
   User user
   Post post
   Date viewed
}
```

`User` and `Post` are the composite ids for `Tracker`

While querying `Post` I want to figure out if the `User` has read the latest update on the `Post`

So the SQL should look something like this:

```
select count(*) as y0_
from nb_post AS this_ 
where (other_conditions) 
   or this_.lastUpdate > (select t_.viewed as y0_ from nb_post_tracker t_ where t_.post=this_.post))
```

My `Criteria` HAS to be on `Post` due to the other_conditions part. Is there a means to pass the current row's `post.id` through a `DetachedCriteria` or `SubQuery`?

Comment: When things get complicated with Hibernate, you don't have to keep trying to figure out how to get Criteria to do what you want. You could instead use a direct SQL query(`Session.createSQLQuery()`). You can still add entities to the query so that it auto populates the results.

Comment: Can I add just this part as the query?      
`this_.lastUpdate > (select t_.viewed as y0_ from nb_post_tracker t_ where t_.post=this_.post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Mark's suggestion I simply went and wrote a some plain old SQL query.
Would be really great if there could be some mechanisms provided OOB in Hibernate for situations where Many-to-Many mapped entities are concerned and programmers want to join the two entities.